# Firebase Push Notification not showing icon in PWA (ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

I've created a PWA application with ReactJS.
I also implemented Firebase Cloud Messaging for displaying push notifications on devices.

When I install my PWA on my android phone I'm getting the correct push notification.

But I can't find how to send an icon to my notification.

I'm triggering the notification with a ASP.NET Core WebApi (2.2) done by the FirebaseAdmin SDK.

My manifest.json file from PWA looks like correct. (192x192 & 512x512 png for icons)
I can install it & it's getting the right app icons.

My code to trigger the notification.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Test()
{
    var message = new Message()
    {
        Notification = new Notification()
        {
            Title = "My Title",
            Body = "My Body",
            ImageUrl = "MY IMAGE URL"
        },
        Token = "MY ANDROID APP TOKEN"
    };

    await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message);

    return Ok();
}
```

I can't find a way to add the Icon. (Now it's default gray with the first letter of my app: E)

Also tried the following code but the Android part isn't doing a thing.

```
var message = new Message()
{
    Android = new AndroidConfig()
    {
        Notification = new AndroidNotification()
        {
            Title = "My Title",
            Body = "My Body",
            ImageUrl = "MY IMAGE",
            Icon = "MY ICON",
            ClickAction = "MY URL"
        }
    },
    Notification = new Notification()
    {
        Title = "My Title",
        Body = "My Body",
        ImageUrl = "MY IMAGE"
    },
    Token = "MY TOKEN"
};

await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message);
```

Icon on Android device.
Image is showing when expanding the notification.
[image: Icon on Android device]

If I use the api provided by Firebase:

> https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

I can send a notification icon & this is working.
How can I get this working with the FirebaseAdmin SDK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem...

I'm using the wrong type of "Notification" in my code.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Test()
{
    var message = new Message()
    {
        Webpush = new WebpushConfig()
        {
            Notification = new WebpushNotification()
            {
                Title = "My Title",
                Body = "My Body",
                Icon = "MY ICON"
            },
        },
        Token = "MY TOKEN"
    };

    await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message);

    return Ok();
}
```

With **WebpushConfig** & **WebpushNotification**, I'm getting exactly what I want.

Comment: I'd be curious to know how you set your click action on this new way?